# MySQL on an Alpine python image is failing - Error loading shared library libmariadb?

Tags: python, docker

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

...

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc libffi-dev openssl-dev musl-dev mariadb-dev \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /code/requirements/production.txt \
    && apk del .build-deps gcc libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev mariadb-dev

...
```

Requirements:

```
django==2.2.9
mysqlclient==1.4.6
gunicorn==20.0.4
django-bootstrap3==12.0.3
django-fsm==2.7.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

When I run the application I get this from django:

```
ImportError: Error loading shared library libmariadb.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

How can I fix this as I have already installed the [MySQL db adapter recommeneded](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-9-installing-popular-packages-on-alpine)?

Answer (score 11):

I found the issue on [docker-alpine github](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/181)

The solution was to add the `mariadb-connector-c-dev` package, before installing dependencies.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev
```

Comment: Even better though is to use something other than alpine for python when connecting to MySQL

Comment: You can actually just use `apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on alpine 14 with either of them packages installed

Comment: It works, you save my day!

Comment: Works nicely! Thank you!